# How would we make concrete on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, materials

Bringing building materials to the moon would be costly. It would be better to just create materials on the Moon.

Comment: Microwaving the regolith is the usual solution

Comment: This is a bit broad @opaque_dragon, and there's also significant material just a google search away, that's generally not a good combination for a question on this site. Is there something from your research you don't understand?

Comment: Here's what more concrete questions about concrete might look like 1) [Mars: Readily usable sulfur for sulfur concrete?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14204/12102) 2) [What series of devices would you need to deliver to the Martian surface to manufacture concrete entirely in-situ?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19219/12102) 3) [How thick would a Marscrete structure need to be to provide adequate protection against radiation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19681/12102) 4) [Are there relevant resources on the Moon for civil engineering?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8133/12102)

Comment: ...5) [Low energy cements for Mars and Callisto. Waterless cement for the Moon. Any good candidates?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26846/12102) 6) [What's required to construct a space port on the Moon or Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14908/12102)

Comment: 7) [Expected differences between concrete prepared on the ISS and matched samples prepared on Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29453/12102)